# Why did the python version not switch after conda switched the environment？

Tags: python, linux, conda

python3.7.12 should be the python version of the hsm environment

```
(hsm) leelee@ubuntu-PowerEdge-T440:~/tools/hsm-master/predict$ which python
/home/leelee/miniconda3/envs/hsm/bin/python
(hsm) leelee@ubuntu-PowerEdge-T440:~/tools/hsm-master/predict$ /home/leelee/miniconda3/envs/hsm/bin/python
Python 3.7.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 26 2021, 06:08:21) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
```

But if I type `python` directly, it will return a 3.9.5 python version

```
(hsm) leelee@ubuntu-PowerEdge-T440:~/tools/hsm-master/predict$ python
Python 3.9.5 (default, Jun  4 2021, 12:28:51) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
```

I guess when I type `python`, I entered `/home/leelee/miniconda3/bin/python`

```
(hsm) leelee@ubuntu-PowerEdge-T440:~/tools/hsm-master/predict$ which -a python
/home/leelee/miniconda3/envs/hsm/bin/python
/home/leelee/miniconda3/bin/python
(hsm) leelee@ubuntu-PowerEdge-T440:~/tools/hsm-master/predict$ /home/leelee/miniconda3/bin/python
Python 3.9.5 (default, Jun  4 2021, 12:28:51) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you added Python to the system PATH, which is not recommended when using conda. Simply check your PATH after conda activation and have a look at the sequence of the Python folders.